# Beautiful Soup - Remover uma tag mantendo o Texto

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Tenho as seguintes tags:

```
<p>Projeto N <sup>o</sup> 00.000, DE 00 DE JANEIRO DE 0000.</p>
```

Gostaria de remover a tag  mantendo o texto.
Precisava que ficasse assim:

```
<p>Projeto N o 00.000, DE 00 DE JANEIRO DE 0000.</p>
```

Comment: Esse html é inválido para o Beautifulsoup por conta do `</p>` no começo, ao invés de `<p>`, forneci uma resposta considerando um html válido.

Comment: Obrigado pela correção. Justamente o que precisava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode utilizar [unwrap()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs('<p>Projeto N <sup>o</sup> 00.000, DE 00 DE JANEIRO DE 0000.</p>')

soup.sup.unwrap()     # <sup></sup>
print(soup)           # <p>Projeto N o 00.000, DE 00 DE JANEIRO DE 0000.</p>
```